# Can i save a webpage source html dynamically using VBA in my local machine

Tags: excel, vba

How Can i save a webpage source html dynamically using VBA in my local machine?

Thanks,
Arup

Comment: There are a few ways of accessing webpages using VBA. Are you trying to save the whole page as an html file?

Comment: Yes,Jamie. After that i want my script will extract data from there and save it to the excel and delete the .html file from the local disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple way of getting and saving an html file to your temp folder for working on. It requires a reference to either Microsoft XML 3.0 or Microsoft XML 6.0.

```
Sub GetHTTP()
Dim objHttp As Object
Dim CachedFilePath As String
    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Call objHttp.Open("GET", "http://www.example.com/", False)
    Call objHttp.Send("")
    CachedFilePath = Environ("temp") & "\" & "ReplaceThisWithFilename" & ".html"
    Call CreateFile(CachedFilePath, objHttp.ResponseText)
End Sub

Function CreateFile(FileName As String, Contents As String) As String
' creates file from string contents
Dim tempFile As String
Dim nextFileNum As Long
  nextFileNum = FreeFile
  tempFile = FileName
  Open tempFile For Output As #nextFileNum
  Print #nextFileNum, Contents
  Close #nextFileNum
  CreateFile = tempFile
End Function
```

To delete the file when you're finished with it try:

```
Sub DeleteFile(ByVal FileToDelete As String)
    SetAttr FileToDelete, vbNormal
    Kill FileToDelete
End Sub
```

Comment: what are the references i need to include for this to happen in Excel VBA?

Comment: Once my script will be done to get data from the html page and i want to delete the .html file from local disk. How to do so?

Comment: At the risk of repeating A.Webb, `DOM` `DOM`-`DOM` `DOM`. Follow the link on your other question and read up on `IXMLDomDocument`. If you still have specific questions, you can start a new thread. No one will know you're asking if you ask it here.

Comment: Okie,Jamie can you say me how to delete the .html from the local desk?

Comment: Can you explain it what you wrote above?